# Left join in google big query

Tags: join, left-join, google-bigquery

I have this error "ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table names.

This left join is used only for c.Network, for other cases it is not required. I understand the error but there is no common field between two tables (bigdata:RawDebug.T and bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails). So i cannot reference two tables in "ON" statement.

Any help would be appreciated !!

```
 DEFINE QUERY Test2 
 SELECT 
 HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
 CASE 
  WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'ver%' THEN 'Verizon'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
  ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
 END
 as ActualDebugData 
 FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'))) as d
 LEFT JOIN [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] as c ON c.Mcc = 289 AND c.Mnc = 88
  WHERE d.reason = 50013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
  CASE 
    WHEN LOWER(DebugData) LIKE 'ver%' THEN 'Verizon'
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
    ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
  END AS ActualDebugData 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'))
) AS d
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT Network 
  FROM [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
  WHERE Mcc = 289 AND Mnc = 88 
  LIMIT 1 
) AS c 
WHERE d.reason = 50013
```

or to improve performance (per Felipe suggestion):

```
SELECT 
  HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
  CASE 
    WHEN LOWER(DebugData) LIKE 'ver%' THEN 'Verizon'
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\d+') THEN c.Network
    ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\?',' ')
  END AS ActualDebugData 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bigdata:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP ('2016-05-15'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-15'))
  WHERE reason = 50013      
) AS d
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT Network 
  FROM [bigdata:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
  WHERE Mcc = 289 AND Mnc = 88 
  LIMIT 1 
) AS c
```

Comment: would it be possible to move "WHERE d.reason = 50013" to the sub-select (way better performance probably)

Comment: totally agree - whould be much better to move it inside d sub-select

Comment: I get this error "Field 'd.reason' not found on either side of the JOIN"

Comment: try second query - it should better handle this :o)

Comment: your original query had more issues than just with ON - fixed it too - now first query should work also. but second one is more optimal

Comment: Now, I am trying to change the cross join subquery where I have to access the DebugReason. But it says that d.DebugData is not present in CarrierDetails. I wonder whether cross join cannot be used for referncing 2 tables? For example, CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT Network 
  FROM [red-road-574:RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
  WHERE Mcc = substr(d.DebugData,0,3) AND Mnc = substr(d.DebugData,4,LENGTH(d.DebugReason - 1)) 
  LIMIT 1 
) AS c